# How do I exclude tcl/tk folders in my pyinstaller packed app?

Tags: python, tkinter, wxpython, pyinstaller

I'm developing a software on windows 7 using python(wxPython for UI), and pyinstaller is the tool I use for packaging. But recently after upgrading pyinstaller to 3.1.1, `tcl/tk` folders start to show up in the directory. And with pyinstaller 2.1 bundling the exact same source codes, there's no such folders to be found, which is the way it should be since I never used tcl/tk anywhere.

And I've tried with `a.datas -= TOC([('tcl', None, 'DATA'), ('tk', None, 'DATA')])`, but it doesn't work. So How do I exclude `tcl/tk` during packing?

Answer (score 4):

Hack sys.modules to remove FixTk, and exclude tcl, tk, and tkinter.

So in your pyinstaller `.spec` file include at least:

```
import sys
sys.modules['FixTk'] = None

a = Analysis(['kill_tk_test.py'],
    {...snipped...}
     excludes=['FixTk', 'tcl', 'tk', '_tkinter', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'],
```

Source: @remdragon at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-remove-tkinter-tcl

Comment: This can also be accomplished with the --exclude-module flag for those using the command without a spec file.